# Empty POST in Internet explorer

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer-11, form-data

I need to post a form containing input fields and files using ajax.

This works on Chrome.

My problem is in Internet Explorer(11), I get empty $_POST & $_FILES.
ajax call:

```
frmData = new FormData($("#form_newCOD")[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/upd_newCOD.php',
    data: frmData,
    contentType: false,  
    processData: false, 
    success: function(data)
    {

        alert(succss);
    },
    dataType:'json',
    async: false
});
```

In upd_newCOD.php, I put only var_dump of $_POST and $_FILES to see the content.

upd_newCOD.php

```
<?php
 var_dump($_POST);
 var_dump($_FILES);

 echo json_encode("success");
 ?>
```

The result of POST data and var_dump:
[image]

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#search=FormData there are two bugs with IE11: "Partial support refers to not supporting json as responseType" and "IE10 and 11 do not support synchronous requests, with support being phased out in other browsers too. This is due to detrimental effects resulting from making them".

Comment: thanks Peter for your reply, I changed dataType:'text' and async: true, and return echo "success", I got the same problem !!